# Standard deviation squared is variance. What is standard error of the mean squared?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, variance, t-test, mean

Is it correct to say that there is a sample variance and a mean variance, and their square roots are the standard deviation and the standard error of the mean, respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
This question only comes up because many text books (in print) and many people, when speaking, are sloppy in their language.

A mathematical expression for a distribution usually has a variance and a standard deviation ( the square root of the variance). This is often expressed in the equation for the density or distribution function as one of the parameters.

A sample of observations has a standard deviation and a variance (its square) that are computed from the observations.

The mean of a sample of observations is usually an estimate of one of the parameters of the distribution it came from, namely the mean of the distribution. This sample mean usually varies around the distribution mean and standard error is an estimate of this variation. The corresponding variance of the sample mean is the square of the standard error.

In summary, a sample has a standard deviation and a variance. A parameter estimate that is based on a sample of observations has a standard error and a variance.

I have tried to be cautious here. Not all distributions have a mean or a variance. In these cases you can calculate the mean, variance, and standard deviation of a sample and the standard error but they don't tell you anything about the distribution or population.

I don't mean to offend text writers. They should be more careful to explain why we distinguish a standard deviation from a standard error. Everybody should be more careful when they speak.